# How to modify the default SetCookie configuration in servant-auth

Tags: haskell, servant

After successful logging in, servant-auth sets a `JWT-Cookie` cookie in the response. The problem is, it also flags the cookie as `HttpOnly`, which means I can't read the JWT in my single page app. My understanding is that this can be configured with the SetCookie datatype. I've been able to create my own custom `SetCookie` by using `defaultSetCookie { setCookieHttpOnly = False }`. How do I stuff it into the `acceptLogin` function?

Here is my handler for logging in.

```
checkCreds :: CookieSettings
           -> JWTSettings
           -> LoginRequest
           -> App (Headers '[ Header "Set-Cookie" SetCookie
                            , Header "Set-Cookie" SetCookie ]
                            NoContent)
checkCreds cookieSettings jwtSettings LoginRequest{email = email, rawPassword = rawPassword} = do
   maybeUser <- logicForFetchingAndValidatingUser
   -- What do I do with this mySetCookie? 
   let mySetCookie = defaultSetCookie { setCookieHttpOnly = False }
   case maybeUser of
     Just userView -> do
      mApplyCookies <- liftIO $ acceptLogin cookieSettings jwtSettings userView
      case mApplyCookies of
        Nothing           -> throwError err401
        Just applyCookies -> return $ applyCookies NoContent
     Nothing -> throwError err401
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the source of `acceptLogin` and figured out it calls `makeSessionCookie` and `makeXsrfCookie`, then uses the results to create a function for adding headers. I did the same in my code, modyfing the result of `makeSessionCookie` along the way:

```
checkCreds :: CookieSettings
           -> JWTSettings
           -> LoginRequest
           -> App (Headers '[ Header "Set-Cookie" SetCookie
                            , Header "Set-Cookie" SetCookie]
                            NoContent)
checkCreds cookieSettings jwtSettings LoginRequest{email = email, rawPassword = rawPassword} = do
   -- Usually you would ask a database for the user info. This is just a
   -- regular servant handler, so you can follow your normal database access
   -- patterns (including using 'enter').
   maybeUser <- logicForFetchingAndValidatingUser
   case maybeUser of
     Just userView -> do
      mSessionCookie <- liftIO $ makeSessionCookie cookieSettings jwtSettings userView
      case mSessionCookie of
        Nothing -> throwError err401
        Just sessionCookie -> do
          let modifiedSessionCookie = sessionCookie { setCookieHttpOnly = False, setCookieSecure = False }
          xsrfCookie <- liftIO $ makeXsrfCookie cookieSettings
          return $ (addHeader modifiedSessionCookie . addHeader xsrfCookie) NoContent

     Nothing -> throwError err401
```